# split csv into regular intervals

Tags: powershell, batch-file

How to split a csv into folds? I have a csv say with 10 lines. i want to split it into 5 sets , each set having 2 files. first file having 2 rows. Second file having remaining 8.

Next set would have 3,3 and 4,4 in 1 file and remaining in another file and so on

```
id1,id2
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,5
6,6
7,7
8,8
9,9
10,10
```

My Desired output:

```
Set-1-A 
   1,1
   2,2

Set-1-B
    3,3
    4,4
    5,5
    6,6
    7,7
    8,8
    9,9
    10,10

Set-2-A
    3,3
    4,4

Set-2-B
    1,1
    2,2
    5,5
    6,6
    7,7
    8,8
    9,9
    10,10
```

and so on..

Comment: I'm still confused about how you propose on splitting these. Be more explicit.

Comment: Please include exact input files and desired output.

Comment: What language do you want to use here.... batch or PowerShell? Is there anything you have tried? Would be nice to see _something_ so we can help you improve it.

Comment: This is required as a one time activity and i'm not very particular about the language used. To begin with, i want to know if i need to use any code at all. If there is any handy utility tool available for csv splitting, i can rely on that. If it is really required to write code, maybe i'll look at Powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested loop to grab `n` items from the csv and export to a new file:

```
$Data = Import-Csv .\input.csv
$n = 2
$SliceCount = 1

while($Data)
{
    $Slice = @()
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $n; $i++){
        # shift rows from the input array, one by one
        $Piece,$Data = $Data
        $Slice += $Piece
    }

    # export each slice to a new csv file
    $Slice | Export-Csv -Path (Join-Path $PWD "output_$($SliceCount).csv") -NoTypeInformation
    $SliceCount++
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: *Code modified as reply to the comments*

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F %%a in ('find /C /V "" ^< input.txt') do set "lines=%%a"
set /P "sets=There are %lines% lines, enter number of sets: "
set /A linesPerSet=lines/sets
del set*-?.csv 2> NUL

rem Initialize the indicators of all sets
for /L %%s in (1,1,%sets%) do set "set[%%s]=1"

rem Activate the first set
set "set=1"
set "set[1]=0"

set "line=0"
for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (

   rem Check all sets and distribute the lines accordingly
   for /L %%s in (1,1,%sets%) do if !set[%%s]! equ 0 (
      rem Output this line to first file of this set
      >> set%%s-A.csv echo %%a
   ) else (
      rem Output this line to second file of this set
      >> set%%s-B.csv echo %%a
   )

   rem Check if the first file of the set must change
   set /A line+=1, lineMODlinesPerSet=line%%linesPerSet
   if !lineMODlinesPerSet! equ 0 (
      rem Change the first file of set
      set /A set+=1
      for /L %%s in (1,1,!sets!) do set /A set[%%s]=set-%%s
   )

)
```

Output:

```
C:\> test.bat
There are 10 lines, enter number of sets: 5

C:\> type set*.csv

set1-A.csv

1,1
2,2

set1-B.csv

3,3
4,4
5,5
6,6
7,7
8,8
9,9
10,10


set2-A.csv

3,3
4,4

set2-B.csv

1,1
2,2
5,5
6,6
7,7
8,8
9,9
10,10


set3-A.csv

5,5
6,6

set3-B.csv

1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
7,7
8,8
9,9
10,10


set4-A.csv

7,7
8,8

set4-B.csv

1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,5
6,6
9,9
10,10


set5-A.csv

9,9
10,10

set5-B.csv

1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,5
6,6
7,7
8,8
```

Comment: I need something similar. But the rows in set1 should always be 2 and rows in set2 should always be 8.

Comment: set B should always hold all the rows that are not in set A

Comment: Code fixed, see the edit. You should be much clearer in your descriptions from the very beginning...